# How can I get each result of different function with one original value?

Tags: c++, function, variables, reference, pass-by-reference

Using references, define each function that meets the following requirements.

1. A function that increases the value of an int variable passed as an argument by one.
2. A function that changes the sign of an int variable passed as an argument.

I got val1: 11, val2: 21 and val1: -11, val2 : -21 for the result.

I want to put the original values in 1 and 2 respectively, but the value entered in first one and it is applied to second one.

My question is, I want to get val1: 11, val2: 21 and val1: -10, val2: -20 for the result.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void AddFunc(int &val1, int &val2) {
    val1++;
    val2++;
}

void ChanSign(int &val1, int &val2) {
    if(val1 < 0) {
        val1 = -val1;
    }
    else {
        val1 = -val1;
    }
    
    if(val2 < 0) {
        val2 = -val2;
    }
    else {
        val2 = -val2;
    }
}

int main() {
    int val1, val2;

    cout << "Enter the first value" << endl;
    cin >> val1;

    cout << "Enter the second value" << endl;
    cin >> val2;

    AddFunc(val1, val2);
    cout << "val1: " << val1 << endl;
    cout << "val2: " << val2 << endl;

    ChanSign(val1, val2);
    cout << "val1: " << val1 << endl;
    cout << "val2: " << val2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, you want to change the sign of 11 and 21 first and then increment them by one?

Comment: Oh, I mean I entered 10 for the val1 and 20 for the val2. I'd like to remain both values for the each function val1 = 10 and val2 = 20. Then I want to get increment = val1: 11, val2: 21. And invert sign = val1: -10, val2: -20.

Comment: I got val1: 11, val2: 21 for the increment already. But when I try to get invert sign of the original values, the result show me val1: -11, val2: -21. I want to make them val1: -10, val2: -20

Comment: You won't be able to retain the old value after you call `AddFunc` since the function will operate (and mutate values) via references to the supplied variables.

Comment: Is there any possible way to do it?

Comment: Yes, there are. E.g. you may want to supply a different pair of variables for the second call.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Thank you so much!